# Python Loop counter returning 0

Tags: python, runtime, loop-counter

I am coding a decision tree and a confusion matrix and I added loop counters to determine the run time of my code but it returns me 0.

```
L = 0
def creatematrixnull(target):
    global L
    uniquetarget =unique(target)
    # we specifie the type to ease the plot
    dataframe=pd.DataFrame(columns=uniquetarget,index=uniquetarget, dtype='int32')
    for i in range(len(uniquetarget)):
        dataframe.iloc[i]=[0]*len(uniquetarget)
        L=L+1
    return dataframe 
    creatematrix=creatematrixnull(targettest)
print(L)
```

This is an example of what I am talking about

Comment: What does the targettest data look like? It also seems you have formatted it incorrectly, the `creatematrix` function call should not be indented

Comment: Also please where is the unique function defined or sourced from?

Comment: @profnotime, `unique` is from **numpy**

Comment: Okay I thought it was a custom definition. Thanks @Cypherjac

Comment: Oh sorry about this @Cypherjac yes now it gives me 8

Comment: I still get 0 for the other ones